# formatting of aspx file in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, formatting

I have a file with a lot of this kind of thing in it:

```
<div>
    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="File Name:" ID="lblFileName"></asp:Label>
</div>
```

How can I get the formatter to change it to shows like this:

```
<div>
    <asp:Label
        runat="server"
        Text="File Name:"
        ID="lblFileName">
    </asp:Label>
</div>
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> will format the whole document for you in Visual Studio.

If you want to change how Visual Studio auto formats the HTML - which I think is what you are asking - you can easily change by going to Tools | Options | Text Editor | HTML | Formatting.

In there, there is an option to wrap tags to a specific length - which is what you are after.